# Cant start new activity. It keeps crashing

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest

When pressing the button, new activity should open but app instantly crashes. I have searched for answer and making a few adjustments to my code and only thing i dont know how to do is Manifest, can u help me with that?

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="Starting.Programm"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<application android:label="@string/app_name"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
    <activity android:name="MainActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="InformationActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              >
        </activity>
</application>
```

MainActivity:

```
package Starting.Programm;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends InformationActivity
{

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


}
 public void startJourney(View view) {
     Intent intent = new Intent(this, InformationActivity.class);
     startActivity(intent);

}
}
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" 
>
<Button android:id="@+id/button_StartApp"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:text="@string/button_StartApp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="115dp" 
    android:onClick="startJourney"
/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And next activity which should be opening

```
package Starting.Programm;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;


class InformationActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.information);


}

}
```

Comment: Show stackstrace

Comment: `android:name="MainActivity"` is wrong, you have to use the complete name ( including package name) or use the dot notation `android:name=".MainActivity"` if the activity is inside the package (without other sub-packages)

Comment: @Deni Erdyneev Cant show stacktrace cuz launching on my mobile phone and cant launch VD cuz it says that there is no system images installed for this target, but i have downloaded everything from SKD manager....

Comment: @TheProfesor you can see stacktrace on your mobile phone as well. Just turn on ADB USB debigging in Settings -> Developer options and choose your phone in Logcat. Also choose No Filter on top right Logcat corner, because logs could be cleaned after crash

Comment: @Deni Erdyneev okey i turned on usb debugging. Whats next? :D(sorry i am kinda new to this shit)

Comment: post your logcat

Answer (score 0):

Add dot to end of pacakager name
    `package="Starting.Programm."`

Answer (score 0):

```
<activity> android:name=".InformationActivity" </activity>
```

Remove     `android:label="@string/app_name"` too. I don't think it is needed.